# Strange behaviour drawing lines with multido and trigonometric functions

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, multido

I'm trying to produce Taylor diagrams to compare statistically data sets. Here is the code as a first approach to such diagram.

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5.75,5.75)
   \psaxes(0,0)(4,4)
   \begin{psclip}{\pswedge(0,0){4}{0}{90}}
     \multido{\ra=1+1}{4}{%
       \pscircle[linewidth=1pt](2.6;0){\ra}%
       \psplot[algebraic]{0}{\ra}{sqrt(\ra*\ra - x*x)}}
     \multido{\rx=0.0+0.1}{10}{%
       \pstVerb{/pen \rx\space 1 div ACOS def}
       \psplot[linecolor=green]{0}{4}{x pen TAN mul}}
  \end{psclip}
  \multido{\ry=0.0+0.1}{10}{%
     \rput{! \ry\space 1 div ACOS RadtoDeg}(! \ry\space 4 mul 16 \ry\space 4 mul  
          dup mul sub sqrt){\psPrintValue{\ry\space 1 div ACOS RadtoDeg}}}
\end{pspicture}
```

The problem is with the second loop that draws the green lines giving:

[image]

Note the two green lines close to 45 degrees (should only be one). The slopes are from angles corresponding to a 1/10 division of the x axis. Surely the code can be written more easily or in a more compact way but I would appreciate to know why this code produces such anomaly or what can be wrong.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple `\psline` for it:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-math}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5.75,5.75)
\psaxes(4,4)
\begin{psclip}{\pswedge(0,0){4}{0}{90}}
    \multido{\ia=1+1}{4}{%
        \pscircle[linewidth=1pt](2.6;0){\ia}%
        \psplot[algebraic]{0}{\ia}{sqrt(\ia*\ia - x*x)}}
    \multido{\rx=0.0+0.1}{10}{%
        \psline[linecolor=green](!4 \rx\space ACOS RadtoDeg PtoC)
    }
    \end{psclip}
    \multido{\ry=0.0+0.1}{10}{%
        \rput{! \ry\space ACOS RadtoDeg}(! \ry\space 4 mul 16 \ry\space 4 mul  
        dup mul sub sqrt){\psPrintValue{\ry\space ACOS RadtoDeg}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative solution:

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5.75,5.75)
\psaxes(4,4)
\begin{psclip}{\pswedge(0,0){4}{0}{90}}
  \multido{\ia=1+1}{4}{%
      \pscircle[linewidth=1pt](2.6;0){\ia}%
      \psarc(0,0){\ia}{0}{90}
  }
    \multido{\rx=0.0+0.1}{10}{%
        \psline[linecolor=green](!4 \rx\space ACOS RadtoDeg PtoC)
    }
\end{psclip}
\multido{\ry=0.0+0.1}{10}{%
    \rput{! \ry\space ACOS RadtoDeg}(!4.1 \ry\space ACOS RadtoDeg 1 sub PtoC){%
        \psPrintValue{\ry\space ACOS RadtoDeg}}}
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried through \psline but the code was more complex. what PtoC stands for ?.

Comment: @user1259970: `PtoC` stands for a transforming operator that transforms Polar `r Θ` to Rectangular `x y`.  Note that `Θ` must be in degrees.

Comment: @user1259970: `\psplot{0}{4}{\rx\space ACOS RadtoDeg tan x mul}` is the same with `psplot`.  You have a problem with your definition and angle 45 degrees.